# Why is the ellipsoid method numerically unstable?

Tags: linear-programming

In the [Ellipsoid method wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid_method) under the performance section, it is mentioned that the Ellipsoid method often times is numerically unstable in practice: "On even "small"-sized problems, it suffers from numerical instability and poor performance in practice". I am wondering if there are any theoretical justifications of this? I implemented the algorithm just for fun, and it seems to perform fine on even "large" instances that I threw at it.

Of course I understand that it is not as fast as interior-point algorithms in practice, but I read from many sources about the "numerical instability" of the Ellipsoid algorithm, so I am a bit confused about the difference between what I am observing in my code and the consensus of instability. In addition, the Ellipsoid method is very useful when you have an exponential number of constraints, but a polynomial time separability oracle, which is something practical solvers cannot deal with in practice but which the Ellipsoid method can.

Is there any **theoretical justification** on why, and when, it is numerically unstable?